# MySQL: throw something like IllegalStateException howto

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have:** procedure which can be launched in two modes: the first - standard mode, and the second - test mode. In the second mode my stored proc doesn't change anything but logging and  checks some intermediate states.

**I want:** if some intermediate conditions are wrong (for example I'm sure that the query should return 3 rows instead of 2) I want to throw something like `IllegalStateException`.

**Problem:** `SIGNAL` statement requires me to point `SQLSTATE`, but I don't know which `SQLSTATE` to choose, because I've got logical error.

**Question:** *How to throw something like IllegalStateException in MySQL?*
c
**P.S:** I don't want to handle that exception, I just want to throw it and interrupt the query.

Comment: Are you asking *which* SQLSTATE number to use?

Comment: @N.B. not only. I'm asking (from fried's account) howto totally stop the procedure and point that something wrong with logical state. Do I need to handle `SQLState`

Comment: You don't need to handle SQLSTATE from within MySQL code. If you create a procedure that sends SQLSTATE signal, it will stop whatever is being processed. Since you didn't say which language you're using, it's hard to tell how exactly to proceed but the MySQL driver should throw an exception and you handle the error from there, along with the status code from SQLSTATE and message.

Comment: @N.B. I just launch my queries in Mysql Workbench. No need to handle signals anywhere

Comment: Can you post some code so we can see how you plan to do this exception-like behaviour? It seems to me that you might be overcomplicating something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Exception is used when it's supposed that something will process the exception. How are you going to handle the exception result?

May be it's better to return some result (make a function or define out parameter or place something in the result set returned by the procedure.)

Then you can pass parameter (to distinguish whether you need check or need change) adn handle the procedure return result.

Comment: thank you for answering my question. I just posted it from another account. I have no mind to handle it. I just want to interrupt all procedures and log that something going wrong. I mean I can't handle that exception and there is no sense to continue query if procedure is in wrong logical state